# From javascript object to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to store an object in an array, but the object comes with (somekind of) name...
I wrote now the following code:

```
class Entry {
  constructor() {
    this.id = "";
    this.txt = "";
  }
}

let array = [
    {
    "id": "1",
    "txt": "Cat"
    },
    {
    "id": "2",
    "txt": "Dog"
    },
    {
    "id": "3",
    "txt": "Tiger"
    },
    {
    "id": "4",
    "txt": "Bear"
    }
]
let old = array.filter(e => e.txt != "");
console.log(old);
let pusher = array.push(new Entry());
newer = pusher.filter(e => e.txt != "");
console.log(newer);
```

If I console.log(array) in Chrome, then I get this:

```
(5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, Entry]
0: {id: "", txt: ""}
1: {id: "", txt: ""}
2: {id: "", txt: ""}
3: {id: "", txt: ""}
4: Entry {id: "", txt: ""}
length: 5
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Why do I get the word Entry? It stays in the array, not only as view in the console.

Comment: it's an instance of `Entry`.

Comment: As people commenting on your previous question told you - it's just how the console display it because it's an `Entry` instance, while the others aren't. But since the structure is the same, there should be no difference to consuming code.

Comment: because you pushed an instance of Entry class

Comment: Dear VLAZ, there is a difference. I do filtering the array after. When there is the new Entry in, I get an error. That means, it's not only a display issue about the console.

Comment: Nina Scholz and Saokat Ali, what is the correct way to push this correctly?

Comment: @FishWave what's the error you get?

Comment: accounting.js:1124 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at accounting.js:1124
    at Array.find (<anonymous>)
    at saveEntry (accounting.js:1124)
    at saveAsNewEntry (accounting.js:1107)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (VM26 index.html:1)

Comment: This error cannot come from this code. You should include a [mcve] if you want us to look into it more - right now, it's impossible to say anything for certain.

Comment: VLAZ, try the code above, I added the filter function, so you can see the error in console.

Comment: You get an error because toy do `let pusher = array.push(new Entry());` but `push` returns a *number* not a new array. So, when you call `pusher.filter(e => e.txt != "")` it says `pusher.filter is not a function`. If you instead call `array.filter(e => e.txt != "")` there is no error and the code works as expected - you get an array with all the items where `txt` is not an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Very first you're trying to add the instance of Entry class in an array that why it returns wrong output.

you can hack this problem using create the normal object

create Entry object in below way

```
var Entry = { id:0,txt:""}
```

now you can used this object and set the new values and push into the array

```
Entry.id = 10
Entry.txt = "stack"
array.push(Entry);
```